# nlohmann json has a string member called name, how can I check it is null or valid string

Tags: linux, c++14, nullptr, nlohmann-json

I know that I have this:

```
json var["thirdName"].get<std::string>().c_str();
```

It is used in C++. The protocol says this member is mandatory, but lots of people don't have third name.

I got exception if it is

```
nullptr;
```

, because I can say

```
var["thirdName"] = nullptr;
```

How can I easily check if it is valid or not?

I've found only one very complex form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the count method:

```
if (var.count("thirdName") > 0) {
  ...
}
```

Personally, I would omit the `> 0`:

```
if (var.count("thirdName")) {
  ...
}
```